# Since simultaneity is relative, how can an observer in a different reference frame explain the outcome of an experiment which depends on simultaneity?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

For an example, two light rays are emitted from the opposite ends of a moving train towards the midpoint, where lies a mechanism which cuts a tomato if the rays arrive simultaneously and does nothing if they don't.

For observers in the train, the tomato would be cut and the reason why would be clear. For observers at rest on the rail platform, the tomato would still be cut, but since the rays did not arrive simultaneously, the mechanism would not make sense to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since simultaneity is relative, how can an observer in a different reference frame explain the outcome of an experiment which depends on simultaneity?

Actually, this is essentially the explanation why no experiment’s outcome can depend on the simultaneity of two spatially separated events.

> a mechanism which cuts a tomato if the rays arrive simultaneously and does nothing if they don't

The arrival of the light rays to the same location at the same time is frame independent. It is only the simultaneity of spatially separated events whose simultaneity is relative, but the simultaneity of spatially co-located events is invariant.

Comment: Thanks for replying! If the rays are emitted from the walls toward the midpoint, an observer inside the train will see that they arrive simultaneously at the midpoint. However, to an observer on the platform, the midpoint is moving away from one ray and toward the other, so they'll arrive separately. How can I conciliate this with the statement that "the arrival of the light rays to the same location at the same time is frame independent"?

Comment: By accepting that you're wrong in your impression that they reach the midpoint at different times.  To the observer outside the train, the rays will appear to have been *emitted* at different times.

Comment: @polytheneman in all reference frames the rays reach the tomato at the same time. Different frames disagree about when the rays were emitted. You seem to have it backwards

Comment: I had completely overlooked the moment of the emission. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no disagreement about the simultaneity of two events that take place at the same location. You can convince yourself of this using the Lorentz transformation. In the Einstein train thought experiment, there is disagreement as to whether the lightning bolts struck the front and the rear of the train car at the same time. But both observers agree that the light from the front of the train car reaches the observer at the center of the car first.

If the car occupant had a device that cut a tomato if two spatially separated events were simultaneous and the tomato is cut, that is a physical fact and the platform observer would have to agree it happened. But even though the events are not simultaneous to the platform observer, he can calculate that they are simultaneous to the car occupant, so he would agree that the tomato should be cut.

Comment: "But even though the events are not simultaneous to the platform observer, he can calculate that they are simultaneous to the car occupant, so he would agree that the tomato should be cut." So the mechanism which cuts the tomato would make sense to the platform observer if and only if he calculated that the events were simultaneous in relation to the train observer. But the mechanism still doesn't make sense physically in his frame, going against the idea that physical laws should work in all frames. He shouldn't have to account for another reference frame in order for things to make sense.

Comment: Cutting a tomato is not a physical law. It's an event. The mechanism is calibrated in the frame of the car so it works based on the timing of events in that frame.

Comment: A non-relativistic example - suppose the car observer is recording a tone emitted by a source of sound, with frequency f, that's at rest in the platform observer's frame. If the car is moving toward the sound, the device would record a frequency f' > f due to the Doppler effect. Suppose further that the device is designed to cut a tomato if it detects a frequency f' and so a tomato is cut. Would that make sense to the platform observer?